# Changing order of font style

Tags: fonts, qt4

Is it possible to change the order of font style?

[image]

In qtconfig-qt4, the default style was no longer Regular. Is it possible to re-order it?

Maybe with something in /etc/fonts/conf.d? Anyone know it?